# How to apply effects to a unicode character in CSS?

Tags: html, css, frontend

How can I apply various effects, like increasing its size etc., using CSS to this arrow

https://jsfiddle.net/tnfLc58h/

So far I've been able to change its color.

HTML

```
<div class="down-arrow">

</div>
```

CSS

```
.down-arrow:after {
    content:'\2193';
    color: red;
    }
```

edit: I want to make it responsive.

Comment: You must ask about a specific effect. *Various effects* is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a pseudo element is an inline element, you need for example to give it `display: inline-block` (or `block`) for it to respond to width/height settings (though not if only to change font properties of course, as some comments assumed I meant).

```css
.down-arrow:after {
  content:'\2193';
  display: inline-block;    /*  or block  */
  background: lightgray;
  color: red;
  height: 32px;
  width: 40px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="down-arrow">
</div>
```

Comment: I think it can work without inline-block or block.

Comment: @uitwaa Show me a fiddle where it works without `inline-block`/`block` and I delete my answer

Comment: Height and width change the size of the box, not arrow. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @uitwaa If you read my answer more properly you'll see that is exactly what I wrote

Comment: got it. Thanks! https://jsfiddle.net/tnfLc58h/3/

Answer (score 0):

To increase the size of the content, you should set the `font-size`

Like so :

```
.down-arrow:after {
  content:'\2193';
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px; // change to whatever
 }
```

See updated [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tnfLc58h/1/)

Comment: @uitwaa - You're welcome. Please mark my solution as accepted if it answers your question.